# Remove time slot in left pane - Weekly view - Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

is it possible to remove the timeslot in left pane in week view.

i want to place the appointments randomly in a day, since in day i can more than 30 appointments so just want to display it in a day. No need to consider the time factor.

[remove time slot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBee9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use such css:

```
.fc-axis, .fc-time {
    display:none;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/em7wpga6/)